# How do I prevent a standard user from accessing or opening files in %appdatalocal%\Microsoft\Windows\iNetCache without interfering with app usage?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-profiles, web-filtering, appdata

Without interfering with regular app/program usage, I am trying to prevent my non-admin user's access to:

```
%appdatalocal%\Microsoft\Windows\iNetCache
```

- **Use Case:** preventing users *(including me)* from downloading distractions via peculiar bypasses into `iNetCache`, then copying those files wherever else
- It would be ideal if `iNetCache` access can be revoked in such a way that files can't be copied + opened, or the folder traversed

Is this at all doable?

Comment: The path listed doesn't exist `%AppData%` resolves to `...\AppData\Roaming`, whereas `%AppDataLocal%` resolves to `...\AppData\Local`. Since everything within `%UserProfile%` is a part of the User Profile, the user it belongs to needs read/write access to almost all subfolders and files - you can remove write permissions for `...\iNetCache`, but as to whether that will create issues, that's a wait and see since that's an unsupported use case of the User Profile.

Comment: Oops, my bad on the path. And fair enough on the rest, thank you for your time ;v;b